# Connect postgresql database to codeigniter

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I have been connecting postgresql with codeigniter give error there is no connection and the db driver is invalid or not found what should i do ?

```
A Database Error Occurred
could not find driver

Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php

Line Number: 518
```

Be kind and suggest a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed the PHP extension for postgres?

Comment: this is required i'll install the extension and revert back to you. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

check your Database.php file in config folder.
add dns and other details. before that you must be ready with postgres installed on you server

```
    $db['default']['dsn'] = 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=database_name';
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but my code is different from what you wrote.